# How to join 2 tables hook_views_data drupal 7

Tags: 7, views

I have 3 tables : societe, field_data_field_idsociete, users

Im trying to get data from societe and users. Below is my code for [hook_views_data](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7).

```
$data['societe']['table'] = array(
    'group' => t('Societe'),
    'join' => array(
        'field_data_field_idsociete' => array(
            'left_field' => 'field_idsociete_value',
            'field' => 'societe_id',
        ),
        'users' => array(
            'left_field' => 'entity_id',
            'field' => 'uid',
        ),
    ),
);
```

i got this error :  Unknown column 'societe.uid' in 'on clause'

Comment: You're creating a join from the `societe` table to the `users` table, so you need to make sure there's a `uid` column in the `societe` table. Currently there isn't, hence the error.

Comment: Yes i dont have o column uid in the societe table.
Im trying to make this join for example :

...
WHERE
societe.societe_id = field_data_field_idsociete.field_idsociete_value
AND
field_data_field_idsociete.entity_id = users.uid

Comment: you should do some research on relationships in hook_views_data